# Laravel Nothing to Migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-7

I created migration on my Laravel project using command `php artisan make:migration migration_name` and `php artisan make:model ModelName -mcr`.

When I run `php artisan migrate` the output is `nothing to migrate`.

I check my database, there is only `migration` table which has no row, even `user` table that comes from Laravel does not created.

This issue occurs on my laptop and PC

This is the environment that I use to run Laravel using XAMPP

- Laravel 7.24 and Laravel 5.8.38
- Apache/2.4.39 (Win64)
- PHP 7.3.7
- MariaDB 10.3.16
- Composer 1.10.10

This is the migration code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

//File name = 2020_08_11_064146_create_category_table.php
//File Path = database/migrations

class CreateCategoryTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('category');
    }
}
```

I already try these but found no luck :

1. Run `composer dump-autoload`
2. Run `php artisan migrate:reset` -> nothing to rollback
3. Run `php artisan migrate:fresh`-> dropped all table successfully, migration table created successfully ,nothing to migrate
4. Run `php artisan migrate --path="/database/migrations/"` -> nothing to migrate
5. Run `php artisan migrate:status` -> no migrations found
6. Run `php artisan migrate:install` -> Migration table create successfully, but did not solve the problem

**TLDR** :

What I literally did are :

1. Download Laravel with composer
2. Edit `.env` for connection to database using user `root`
3. Create migration using `php artisan make:migration create_table_category`
4. Run `php artisan migrate`
5. Result = `Migration table create successfully, nothing to migrate`. Database only have table `migrations` with no rows

**EDIT**

Migration can be run if I specify the path completely with file name like `php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/2020_08_11_064146_create_category_table.php"`

Comment: is your migration already in there?

Comment: Do you have any entry in migration table?

Comment: You have not renamed the migration class name and the file name, have you?

Comment: @NaveedAli yes, all the migration files exist in directory `database/migration`

Comment: @diliphirapara my migration has no data, only to create table and it's column

Comment: @timwebley no i haven't. I literally just download Laravel from composer, create the migration then run `php artisan migrate`  and the result is `nothing to migrate`

Comment: have you created the database as well?

Comment: @NaveedAli yes i did, the only table that exist in database is `migrations` which has no row, even the `users` table that comes with laravel is not exist

Comment: your migration is not creating actually

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate:install` at any time? Did you run `php artisan make:migration migration_name` in the correct folder? What name does your migration file have?

Comment: i think u need to rename `database/migration` to  `database/migrations` as u mention above

Comment: @KamleshPaul sorry I did a typo, the files already located  in `database/migrations`, nice catch tho

Comment: @kerbh0lz i tried `php artisan migrate:install` then `php artisan migrate` and the result is `nothing to migrate`. Yes I'm sure since I'm using vscode terminal. My migration file looks normal, I just run `php artisan make:migration migration_name` and didn't touch the file then run the migration

Comment: Try with `php artisan migrate --path="/database/migrations/2020_08_11_064146_create_category_table.php` If above method not work you can try with `--force`

Comment: Very strange. You could create a new Laravel project and see if migrations work there (run `php artisan migrate:install` first). Try `php artisan migrate:fresh` in your current project to drop all tables and start a fresh installation, "_Nothing to migrate._" also pops up if all migrations have already run (check using `php artisan migrate:status`). Try `php artisan session:table` to create a migration file for the sessions table and run `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: @sta wow nice one this one returns much info, it return error `no such file directory E:\Indra\[0] Coba2\test migration/C:/Program Files/Git/database/migrations/2020_08_11_064146_create_category_table.php` but my migration in `E:\Indra\[0] Coba2\test migration\database\migrations`. I don't know why it happens, I am using `bash` via vscode terminal

Comment: @kerbh0lz all command run successfully, the final output is `no migrations found` and the migration file for `sessions` is created

Comment: That might be because of the leading `/`, try `php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/2020_08_11_064146_create_category_table.php"`. Something seems faulty in your bash/terminal setup, check your PATH

Comment: @kerbh0lz oh you are right,  the migration run successfully and table is created in database, but when I run `php artisan migrate:reset` it return `Migration not found: 2020_08_11_064146_create_category_table`. Then I manually reset the migration and run `php artisan migrate` which return `nothing to migrate`

Comment: "_Then I manually reset the migration_" What does that mean? How do you do that? Personally I never reset migrations manually and almost always use `php artisan migrate:fresh` in development

Comment: Please show  your connection config in `config/database.php` file.

Comment: @kerbh0lz delete all your table and empty the `migrations` table. That's what I did when I don't know that `php artisan migrate:reset` exist

Comment: @egretos here https://codeshare.io/ayk3Rq. By the way I don't change anything in `config/database.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled into [this post](https://laravel.io/forum/08-10-2014-nothing-to-migrate) which described that the problems caused by project path that have character hyphens '-'

My project does not have those characters, but it has 'weird' characters and that is opening and closing square bracket '[ ]', so I thought to change it.

My root project directory path is `F:\Indra\Kerja\[1] Personal\Personal profile\web` so my migration path is `F:\Indra\Kerja\[1] Personal\Personal profile\web\database\migrations`

Notice there's folder named `[1] Personal`, that's the culprit

**I renamed my folder to `Personal` and voila the migration works normally.**

I was curious so I try different folder name and I get and interesting result:

- `[asdasd]Personal` -> ***migration doesn't work for some reason***
- `[1 Personal`-> migration work
- `]1Personal`-> migration work
- `][1 Personal`-> migration work
- `[]Personal` -> migration work

So I have to change my folder name

**Important Note**:

- My Operating system is Windows 10 Pro Version 1909 Build 18363.1082
- I also tried to give hyphens '-' to my project directory like this `F:\Indra\Kerja\my-project-test`, and expect that the migration won't work, but the migration works without a problem

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not the best solution for such situation, but You can try to define migration path hard in `AppServiceProvider`:

```
/**
 * Register Custom Migration Paths
 */
$this->loadMigrationsFrom([
    database_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'migrations'
]);/
```

Comment: I tried to put it in both `register` and `boot` method but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

remove all non alphanumeric characters from the path
ie the path to your project should be c:/code/mylaravelproject